# Javascript/ moment.js Convert timestamp from one country time zone to another country time zone irrespective of local time zone

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I need solution to Convert timestamp from one country time zone to another country time zone irrespective of local time zone. I am looking for some help.

Consider that My local time zone is Canada(GMT-5). 11:32 am Tuesday, 6 December 2022 (GMT-5)
I do have date and time in string format from Alaska time zone AK, USA (GMT-9) 7:32 am Tuesday, 6 December 2022 (GMT-9) to Germany time zone 5:32 pm Tuesday, 6 December 2022 (GMT+1). Logic should return me  5:32 pm Tuesday, 6 December 2022

function should take 3 arguments like date in string format, from time zone, to time zone. And it should return a date and time in to time zone format

Function convertTimeZone(date, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone){
}

Comment: Try to make a more specific question. Add method parameter `date, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone` sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`moment.tz constructor`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) to parse your input timestamp.

The resulting date can then be converted to the output timezone using the [`.tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) method.

We'd then use the [`.format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to output the desired timestamp.

```js
function convertTimeZone(date, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone, outputFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') { 
    const from = moment.tz(date, fromTimeZone);
    return from.tz(toTimeZone).format(outputFormat);
}

const date = '2022-12-06 11:32';
const fromTimeZone = 'Canada/Eastern';
const timeZones = [fromTimeZone, 'UTC', 'US/Alaska', 'Europe/Berlin'];
console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(22), 'Time');
for(let toTimeZone of timeZones) {
    console.log(`${toTimeZone}`.padEnd(22), convertTimeZone(date, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

take the time from the timezone and convert it to another timezone.
Moment works like this as chaining it.

```
moment.tz('2022-12-30 12:15', fromTz).tz(toTz);
```

Comment: According to the [moment.tz documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/), '2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z' will be parsed as UTC regardless of the supplied timezone because it has an offset: "*The offset is only taken into consideration when constructing with an array, **string without offset***…".